# How to read mail with java mail API (String cannot be cast to Multipart)

Tags: java, email, gmail, jakarta-mail, inbox

I am trying to write a simple code that will read messages from gmail inbox.
I have found some examples, but non of them is working. 
Most promising is code I've found on CompilatimEerror.com, BUT whatever I try I get this error:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.mail.Multipart`

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;

public class ReadingEmail {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        try {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
            Store store = session.getStore();
            store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "yourEmailId@gmail.com","password");
            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message msg = inbox.getMessage(inbox.getMessageCount());
            Address[] in = msg.getFrom();
            for (Address address : in) {
                System.out.println("FROM:" + address.toString());
            }
            Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent(); // here it breaks
            BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);
            System.out.println("SENT DATE:" + msg.getSentDate());
            System.out.println("SUBJECT:" + msg.getSubject());
           System.out.println("CONTENT:" + bp.getContent());
        } catch (Exception mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

There is no connection error, as it gets the subject, date, and all this stuff, but the email body is a mystery. There will be no attachments, I will get only simple mails(this is a part of greater project)

What I am looking for is to read the unread mail (and then delete this message, so the inbox will be permanently empty(spam will be deleted manually)).
I lack knowledge about web programing/structures, and all that pop's, imaps and stuff is a blank space. 
Also keep in mind that I am a novice programmer and this is the first time that I go outside of my computer with my code unfortunately straight into the problems of protocols / authentication / getting things from internet.

I went through a lot of pages, but never found an explanation that would allow me to create it myself...

Comment: What is the error you're getting.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.mail.Multipart

Comment: Sometimes you should just google the error / exception you're getting. Let us know if the following link helps you. In short: _"Your message content [is] returning String and you are trying to type cast to Multipart"_ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116465/java-lang-classcastexception-java-lang-string-cannot-be-cast-to-javax-mail-mult

Comment: For me it just says, what the exception says. I cannot cast the body which is orginally a string to ?Multipart?
I tried to cast body to (String) with no multipart mentioned in code, but that wasn't working.

Comment: I solved it finally. Sadly there is not so much help to look in this matter.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to this post. That will help other people who have the same problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you related to [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024191/not-able-to-read-content-of-mail-using-javamail)?

The [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html) has pointers to lots of helpful information, including the [JavaMail project page](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home), [sample code](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Samples), etc.  You'll also find pointers to some useful background material and tutorials [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138267.html).